# Column break in word - continously

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Masters,

I need to PASTE my content in two different column in word. (I have 300 page of old content and 300 page of new content, i want to share my partners this information side by side to compare)

I made two column and instert a column break, but i have to insert column break every page? How can i do this easier?

Any way to insert column break continously, so i just need to copy&paste the contents into the columns?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to use different functionality in Word - Compare

Have your old and new documents in separate files and use the Compare function to show the differences between the two.

More details:

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2007/08/06/comparing-and-combining-documents.aspx

and

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2009/02/17/test2903298.aspx

Comment: I have the old and new content in different file, but i need both of them and show in one document. I not only need the difference. I have to see the old and new side by side in one docs.